# Nsys Profile with MPMD(multiple program and multiple data) simulation

Tags: nvidia, openmpi, hpc, openacc, nsight

I am trying to profile a MPI+OPENACC program with nsys.
I am using OpenMPI(3.1.6) from Nvidia HPC SDK(20.7) with UCX enabled.
There are three exectuables, exec1, exec2, exec3. I want to profile for exec3. But I am failing.
Following is the run script:-

```
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=40
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --output=app.out
#SBATCH --error=app.err
#SBATCH -p Intel_6248_2s_20c_2t_GPU_hdr100_192GB_2933
#SBATCH --exclusive
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4

WRAPPER=/run/acc_round_robin.sh

exec1=$workdir/exec/prog1
exec2=$workdir/exec/prog2
exec3=$workdir/exec/prog3

echo "0 $WRAPPER $exec1> $workdir/file.conf
echo "2-9,11-19,21-29,32-39 $WRAPPER $exec2">> $workdir/file.conf
echo "nsys profile 1,10,20,30,31 $WRAPPER $exec3">> $workdir/file.conf

echo "#!/bin/bash" > $workdir/file1_cmd
echo "srun --multi-prog $workdir/file.conf" >> $workdir/file1_cmd

echo "exit 1" >> $workdir/file1_cmd
chmod +x $workdir/file1_cmd

/usr/bin/time ./CASTING cast ./configure
date
TEND=echo "print time();" | perl

echo "++++ Total elapsed time expr $TEND - $TBEGIN seconds"
```

Run:- sbatch run.sh

Comment: What is the reported error / problem?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Following is the error:-
`3.452 + srun --multi-prog /users/giri/file.conf
srun: error: Invalid task range specification (nsys)
srun: error: Line 3 of configuration file /users/giri/file.conf invalid`

Comment: Configuration File is :- `0 /run/acc_round_robin.sh /giri/exec/prog1 <br/>
2-9,11-19,21-29,32-39 /run/acc_round_robin.sh /giri/exec/prog2 <br/>
nsys profile 1,10,20,30,31 /run/acc_round_robin.sh /giri/exec/prog3`